# std::unique_ptr and pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I want to use `std::unique_ptr` in combination with FreeImage's FITAG. The code in plain C would be:

```
... load image;

FITAG* tag = NULL;
FreeImage_GetMetadata(FIMD_EXIF_EXIF, bitmap, "Property", &tag);
... do some stuff with tag;
FreeImage_DeleteTag(tag);

... delete image;
```

My attempt with unique_ptr:

```
std::unique_ptr<FITAG, void(*)(FITAG*)> tag(NULL, &FreeImage_DeleteTag);
FreeImage_GetMetadata(FIMD_EXIF_EXIF, bitmap, "Property", &tag.get());
```

which obviously returns:

```
cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'pointer' (aka 'FITAG *')
```

How would I solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: No, FreeImage_GetMetadata expects a FITAG**.

Comment: If FreeImage_DeleteTag doesn't have a signature which unique_ptr will accept, then write a wrapper function which does have a necessary signature and which then calls FreeImage_DeleteTag appropriately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reverse the order of operations; first acquire the resource and then construct the `unique_ptr`.

```
FITAG *p = NULL;
FreeImage_GetMetadata(FIMD_EXIF_EXIF, bitmap, "Property", &p);
std::unique_ptr<FITAG, void(*)(FITAG*)> tag(p, &FreeImage_DeleteTag);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tag.get()
```

This returns an r-value. You can't get the address of an r-value( temporary ). Your best bet is to do this instead:

```
auto ptr = tag.get();
FreeImage_GetMetadata(FIMD_EXIF_EXIF, bitmap, "Property", &ptr);
```

This will allow you to pass a FITAG** into the function. If you meant to pass a FITAG* into the function, just remove the & since tag.get() returns the pointer, not the value.

```
FreeImage_GetMetadata(FIMD_EXIF_EXIF, bitmap, "Property", tag.get());
```

Comment: Your first example will compile, but the `unique_ptr` will no longer own the resource allocated by `FreeImage_GetMetadata`.