# unique_ptr and library with C API with pointer to pointer funciton parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Say, I've got a library which initializes an object like this:

```
Type *object;

lib_init(&object); // lib_init takes Type **object as the parameter
```

So, what if I want to use the library with my code which uses smart pointers?
Is this a proper way?

```
Type *pObject;
lib_init(&pObject);
unique_ptr<Type> object(nullptr);
object.reset(pObject);
```

Or is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: does the library gives you a way to clean the object up when it's no longer needed?

Comment: What does the library's documentation say about disposing of the object obtained with `lib_init`? I would expect there to be a corresponding `lib_destroy` or something along these lines. It's unlikely that `delete object` is the right way to dispose of an object allocated by a C language library - but that's what `unique_ptr` would do unless told otherwise.

Comment: Yes, there is `lib_dispose` and I understand that there must be a custom deleter in order to call that function. Actually, the answer to my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24543176/135749. Exactly the behavior that I was looking for. Thank you, everybody.

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap the initialization into a function that returns a unique pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<Type> init_type()
{
  Type* p;
  lib_init(&p);
  return std::unique_ptr<Type>(p);
}
```

Then

```
 std::unique_ptr<Type> object(init_type());
```

Bear in mind that, unless the pointer is to be de-allocated with `delete`, you'll need to provide a custom deleter too. For example, assuming the de-allocation function is `void lib_dispose(Type*)`, then

```
std::unique_ptr<Type, void (*)(Type*)> init_type()
{
  Type* p;
  lib_init(&p);
  return std::unique_ptr<Type, void (*)(Type*)>(p, lib_dispose);
}
```

Comment: Why not returning directly an `unique_ptr` ? (and so that handles also case with custom deleter)

Comment: @Jarod42 No reason. That makes perfect sense. See edit.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, fixed. I don't think `make_unique` is suitable here, because the legacy API requires initializes a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need smart pointer here, you can take the standard library approach for `std::string`/`std::vector` etc. - wrap the pointer in RAII mechanism

```
class CType{
  Type* m_Ptr;

  public:
     CType(){
        lib_init(&m_Ptr);
     }

     ~Ctype(){
        lib_dispose(&m_Ptr);
     }

     //TODO: Copy constructor, move constructor assignment operators..

     operator Type&(){
        return *m_Ptr;
     } 

     operator const Type&() const{
        return *m_Ptr;    
     }

    operator Type*(){
        return m_Ptr;
     } 

     operator const Type*() const{
        return m_Ptr;    
     }

    Type* asPointer(){
         return m_Ptr;
     }
};
```

now use Ctype anywhere you would use regular `Type`, the polymorphism will kick in when you try to use `CType` as `Type*` or `Type&`..